# как передать переменную внутрь объекта в промиссе?

Tags: javascript, api, async-await

```
async function getResponse(first, second) {
  let response = await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}', {
    owner: first,
    repo: second
  });
  console.log(response.data);
}

getResponse('nikolay1990', 'js');
======================================
async function getResponse() {
  let response = await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}', {
    owner: 'Nickolay1990',
    repo: 'study'
  });
  console.log(response.data);

getResponse();
```

При запуске функции не происходит передача параметров в объект, который в параметрах функции request. Пробовал уже и с областями видимости эксперементировать, но ничего не получается.... Верхний пример не работает. Возвращает 404. А нижний срабатывает четко. Кто - нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Что именно не получается. Ваш код вполне себе рабочий

Comment: Какая - то странная проблема... Метод request принимает объект в качестве второго аргумента. Если внутри объекта захардкодить его то он работает, а если я передаю в этот объект переменные инициализированные, то он не срабатывает... Эксперементировал и с областями видимости и т.п. Не получается, работает только хардкод.

Comment: Я в верхний пост, добавил более детальное описание.

Comment: У вас в первом параметре странные {owner} и репо... это не должны быть переменные?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/ru/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28
Вот описание метода и его параметров. А так же пример использования. Он там в примере тоже хардкодит... Но все же... Метод ведь работает если в ручную прописывать . Вы сможете разобраться ?

Comment: Ошибка найдена. Проблема была в том что я не знал имя репозитория и вводил его не правильно. Спасибо:)